# Create JavaScript code from C# method to JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I've an extension method in C# that creates a script, then puts the created script into a view. I want put the created script into a .js file then reference the .js file to the view.
Is there a way to do so?

**C# code:**

```cs
public static HtmlString RenderScript(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    string script = string.Empty +
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >" +
        //do something
        " </script>";
    builder.AppendLine(script);
    return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

**View:**

```
@section Scripts{
    @(Html.RenderScript())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by placing the JavaScript in an a separate file.

```
public static async Task<HtmlString> RenderScriptAsync(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string jsFilePath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsFilePath))
    {
        var js = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return new HtmlString($@"<script type=""text/javascript"">{js}</script>");
    }
}
```

In order for this to work, you need to make the file containing the JavaScript part of your build output by choosing `copy if newer` from the build action section of properties window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, look into [Embedded Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps) if you want to inject the content of files straight into your dll